# 400 features and 100 classes using weka

Tags: classification, cart, ensemble-learning, weka, bagging

I am working on a classification problem, where I have **400 features**(all are numeric), and **100 classes** and I have **26,000 examples** for training.
In my project I am using **Weka** and I have tried different algorithms and so far I have received the best results with the following stack of algorithms:

- Rotation Forest(with 60 Iteration)+Multiclass classifier(1-vs-all)+RepTree-> accuracy **79.9%**
- Bagging(with 60 Iteration)+Multiclass classifier(1-vs-all)+RepTree->accuracy is **79%**

I have tried also to increase the number of Iterations but the accuracy decreases after 60 Iterations

**Q: Is it possible to increase the accuracy, and which algorithm or methodology can be used to achieve better accuracy?**

Comment: Have you tried feature selection?  Weka offers a variety of tools to assist in feature selection. With 400 features,  that might help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used the LMT classifier in weka and it gave me overall success rate around 93%